# Google sheets time formatting won't work for me

Tags: time, google-sheets, formatting, formula

I'm rather new to google sheets, and I'm trying to make a timesheet that will calculate hours and minutes automatically. The problem I'm facing is that the formula always returns a "#VALUE!"-error because "23:15 is a text and cannot be coerced to a number".

I've formatted the cells to time, but it won't recognize the input as hours and minutes. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too, I discovered that you have to change the location:
File > Spreadsheet Setting > Locale > United Kingdom

you will see that now you can type your time correctly with the ":"

Comment: If you use euroes then choose `File > Spreadsheet Settings > Locale > Germany` because otherwise currency will be in pounds instead of euroes. Also guessing that the German locale may be the best compliant with international standards when going forward, but that is just a hunch.

Comment: Ok, I take that back. The locale also affects the language of newly created sheetnames and texts in Pivot tables, so best just to stick to the UK locale and use a custom currency format for euroes.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Format, Number, More Formats, More Date time formats.Select Hour Minute (13:30). Apply this format to all columns (or cells) involved in the calculation.

Here is a copy of my test spreadsheet. I can't get yours to work(?), but this does:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qg1JJU9MELesqllHFOhKFO-jxDf1fJMiIVznU1vNP0w/edit?usp=sharing
```

It is set to your country.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

I've tried this as well as custom formatting, but it still won't read the input correctly.

Here's a link if anyone wanna see what I mean (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EK-f-H-dQPS2HTZ8x2qhndVHaplGueNkUGIo3q0jK0U/edit?usp=sharing)

EDIT: made the link editable for everyone

Comment: Yeah, that's so strange! Kinda reassuring that it's not just me, but extremely annoying that there seems to be something wrong with my sheets..

Thanks a lot for the attention nonetheless! I'll just straight up try and create a new gmail to see if that works.